# Change redirected URL in Scrapy

Tags: scrapy

It is possible to change a redirected url in scrapy?

For example, I crawl an url:

http://someurl.com/A

which has a redirect to

http://redirectedurl.com:8080/A

This url fails because of the port number. The good URL needs to be without a port number, so I would like to change it to

http://redirectedurl.com/A

I tried to update the request.meta with [redirect_urls](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-redirect_urls) having the new url without a port.
The docs says that [MetaRefreshMiddleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#metarefreshmiddleware) obeys the redirect_urls, but no succes

```
meta.update({'redirect_urls': ['http://redirectedurl.com/A '] })
r = Request(url=url, callback=callback, meta=meta)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This question is [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I update my question. Please reconsider it.

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to go deep and try to fix things "under the hood". You can just check if the request was redirected, and then create a new request with the modified URL:

```
import re
if 'redirect_urls' in response.meta:
    new_url = re.sub(":\d+","", response.url)
    yield Request(new_url)
```

Of course, you would add additional checks there, this is just a minimum example.